# MongoDB Atlas Nodejs script - connect takes around 2 to 3 seconds to cluster in singapore

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda, mongodb-atlas

I am using the following snippet to connect to mongo and every new connection takes around 2 to 3 seconds to open. Just wondering if it's MongoDB Atlas' default behaviour, or is there something I am doing wrong.

```
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@<atlasUri>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    console.time('connectionTime');
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
    client.connect(err => {
      console.timeEnd('connectionTime');
      const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
      // perform actions on the collection object
      client.close();
    });
```

My code runs within AWS Lambda function, and I am trying to avoid doing `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;` suggested in https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/best-practices-connecting-to-aws-lambda/. I prefer to close the connection after request finishes.

Answer (score 0):

2-3 seconds is pretty reasonable: it takes mongo a bit of time to set up a connection. According to the doc you linked:

> There is a small initial startup cost of approximately 5 to 10 seconds when the Lambda function is invoked for the first time and the MongoDB client in your AWS Lambda function connects to MongoDB. Connections to a mongos for a sharded cluster are faster than connecting to a replica set. Subsequent connections will be significantly faster for the duration of the lifecycle of the Lambda function.

It takes me 1.5s to connect to a locally running mongo with the node client & 2s to connect to an atlas sandbox instance.